# How to list relations in postgres schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help with a pretty basic Postgres command, but I cannot find a reference anywhere. My cluster is set up like this:

```
database_1
   \- schema_1
   \- schema_2
        \- relation_1
        \- relation_2
        \- ...
   \- relation_3
   \- relation_4
   \- ...
```

I know how to list databases (`\l`), and I know how to list relations in the "default" schema (`\dt`). Heck, I can even list schemas (`\dn`), but I cannot, for the life of me, list the relations within a schema.

Halp!

Thanks,
Joe

---

To pre-clarify, what I'm looking for is this:

```
> \c database_1
You are now connected to database_1
> \somecommand
relation_1
relation_2
>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\dt schema_2.
```

Comment: perfect, thanks :) At the same time I also discovered that asterisk will work with this as well (\dt schema_2.* or \dt schema_*.* etc etc)

Comment: this answer appears out of date

Answer (score 26):

I'll clarify since this is the first result of a google search.

`\dt schema_2` will not list all the relations for `schema_2`.

The correct answer is in the comments of the answer.

```
\dt schema_2.*
```

A more thorough answer can be found here, [List tables in a PostgreSQL schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644152/list-tables-in-a-postgresql-schema)

Answer (score 4):

As of PostgresQL version 11.2 I find that this performs as expected. It lists views and sequences as well, not just tables.

\d schema_2.

If you replace schema_2 with your schema name and leave the dot it appears to work fine.

Some further command instructions are available in a psql connection via \?