# How to list the tables of schemas in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, command, psql, postgresql-9.1, dbtable

When I do a `\dt` in psql I only get a listing of tables in the current schema (`public` by default).

How can I get a list of all tables in all schemas or a particular schema?

Answer (score 803, accepted):

In all schemas:

```
=> \dt *.*
```

In a particular schema:

```
=> \dt public.*
```

It is possible to use [regular expressions with some restrictions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS)

```
\dt (public|s).(s|t)
       List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner 
--------+------+-------+-------
 public | s    | table | cpn
 public | t    | table | cpn
 s      | t    | table | cpn
```

> Advanced users can use regular-expression notations such as character classes, for example [0-9] to match any digit. All regular expression special characters work as specified in Section 9.7.3, except for `.` which is taken as a separator as mentioned above, `*` which is translated to the regular-expression notation `.*`, `?` which is translated to `.`, and `$` which is matched literally. You can emulate these pattern characters at need by writing `?` for `.`, `(R+|)` for `R*`, or `(R|)` for `R?`. `$` is not needed as a regular-expression character since the pattern must match the whole name, unlike the usual interpretation of regular expressions (in other words, `$` is automatically appended to your pattern). Write `*` at the beginning and/or end if you don't wish the pattern to be anchored. Note that within double quotes, all regular expression special characters lose their special meanings and are matched literally. Also, the regular expression special characters are matched literally in operator name patterns (i.e., the argument of `\do`).

Comment: Simply `\dt` is equivolent to `\dt public.*`, am I right?

Comment: How about, say, two specific tables in a specific schema?  Like `\dt public.user_info, public.user_scope`?

Comment: Nevermind, it's easier just to do `\dt public.a; \dt public.b;` on one line.

Comment: it is kind of implicit.. If \dt gives only "public" tables, one would not expect anything more via regular expressions..

Comment: And if your table name contains capital letters you have to quote the schema name like this `\dt "MySchema".*`

Comment: @FrozenFlame It is not! By default it shows whatever is in your `search_path`, and _that_ defaults to `"$user", public.*`. Consequently,
`set search_path=s; \dt` is going to list all tables in the schema `s`.

Comment: This does not list tables of **foreign imported schemas**: *"No matching relations found."*. (See [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html)). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15644435/2414736)
 of @jakub-kania is working.

Answer (score 407):

You can select the tables from `information_schema`

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
```

Comment: very helpful if your interface doesn't support the shortcuts. thanks.

Comment: This is also nice because you could do something like

    select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%whatever%'; 

if you need to know which schema the table is located in. Not sure you can do that with \dt

Comment: Thank you, it works on Amazon Redshift and \dt (accepted answer) doesn't.

Comment: This is the most generally useful answer. information_schema is defined in SQL Standards, and available on most databases that comply

Comment: To exclude views, put `AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'` to the where clause.

Comment: The ACTUAL answer...

Comment: This also lists tables of **foreign imported schemas**! (See [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html)). Therefore the **actual and always working** answer. (`\dt` and `pg_tables` don't)

Answer (score 93):

Alternatively to `information_schema` it is possible to use `pg_tables`:

```
select * from pg_tables where schemaname='public';
```

Comment: note that if you only want the table name is the resultant query it is `SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public';`

Comment: Found a permissions issue with `information_schema` not listing items from the `public` schema, but the `pg_tables` method worked nicely.  Many thanks!

Comment: This does not list tables of **foreign imported schemas**. (See [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html)). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15644435/2414736)
 of @jakub-kania is working.

Answer (score 15):

For those coming across this in the future:

If you would like to see a list of relations for several schemas:

```
$psql mydatabase
mydatabase=# SET search_path TO public, usa;   #schema examples
SET
mydatabase=# \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public | counties        | table | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys | table | postgres
 public | states          | table | postgres
 public | us_cities       | table | postgres
 usa    | census2010      | table | postgres
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are interested in listing all tables in a **particular** schema, I found [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114647) relevant :

```
SELECT table_schema||'.'||table_name AS full_rel_name
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema = 'yourschemaname';
```

Comment: To exclude views, put `AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'` to the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

All of the previous answers has covered the public schemas. However, as Postgres supports multiple schemas, you can do query in other schemas too, just put your schema name in place of public.

For Example:

```
select * from pg_tables where schemaname='your_own_schema_name';
```