# How can I list tables but not views from a Postgres DB, using R?

Tags: r, postgresql, dbi

In `?DBI::dbListTables` we can read :

> This should include views and temporary objects

And indeed it does.

How can I see only tables though, excluding views ?

I'm using the driver `RPostgres::Postgres()` if it matters.

Comment: How about `dbGetQuery` with these queries for [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644152/list-tables-in-a-postgresql-schema/15644435#15644435) and [views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23837)?

Comment: ... so from Tony's links:  `dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'")`

Comment: This seems like a neat way to do it. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it. Do you know what are the different possible values of table_type?

Comment: I'm a bit late, and there's a good answer there already, which is fine by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the system catalog view [`pg_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html) for tables:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM pg_tables")
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html)

> The view `pg_tables` provides access to useful information about each table in the database.

Does not contain views, materialized views or temporary tables, only regular tables (including [`UNLOGGED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-UNLOGGED) tables). See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

You may want to exclude system tables and only retrieve schema and table name:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT schemaname, tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname !~ '^pg_' AND schemaname <> 'information_schema'")
```

I added explicit schema-qualification for the catalog table: `pg_catalog.pg_tables`. Typically not necessary, but to defend against a messed up `search_path` setting. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

[`pg_views`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-views.html) for views - if you need that:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM pg_views")
```

> The view `pg_views` provides access to useful information about each view in the database.